# IServiceCollection does not contain definition for AddMvc()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When ever I try to build the project in visual studio 2015, I am facing the issue in `ConfigureServices` method.
[image]

Comment: Check the version of asp.net-mvc you are trying to use. Looks like you are mixing code for mvc5 and core/mvc6. Your folder structure is for mvc5 but the code you are trying to use is for core/mvc6. If this is a new project then you may have selected the wrong template. if this is an existing project then you are trying to add core to mvc5

Comment: No problem, gad to help. If my comment solved your problem, I've added it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of asp.net-mvc you are trying to use. Looks like you are mixing code for mvc5 and core/mvc6. Your folder structure is for mvc5 but the code you are trying to use is for core/mvc6. If this is a new project then you may have selected the wrong template. if this is an existing project then you are trying to add core to mvc5